# How do I register multiple concrete types using assembly scanning in Autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac

I have an assembly with multiple classes that I'd like to register using assembly scanning in Autofac. Some requirements:

- There is more than one base type that I use to find the concrete types to register.
- It should not register `abstract` classes.
- Scanning should not be wasteful/redundant, if possible.

Based on the documentation, it seems like the straightforward way of doing this shown below. Note that the `Module` implementation is inconsequential here; I'm just showing it for completeness).

```cs
ContainerBuilder builder;
// ...
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assembly).AssignableTo<ExpandableDialog>();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assembly).AssignableTo<Form>();
```

Does this cause assembly scanning with each line? Or can I make this more performant by combining them like so?

```cs
ContainerBuilder builder;
// ...
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assembly)
    .AssignableTo<ExpandableDialog>()
    .AssignableTo<Form>();
```

I feel like the bottom one isn't correct because `AssignableTo` uses logical AND, so it would require classes to implement *both* classes above which is wrong. It should be an OR condition.

What is the correct solution here given my list of requirements above?

Comment: Usually registration is one time operation and I think in most cases you should not be conserned that much about one time operations. Also from the [docs](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/E960450C.htm) description the second one should register only types which are assignable both to `Form` and `ExpandableDialog`.

Comment: Assembly scanning is not a bottleneck in any meaningful way here. Unless you are dealing with a ludicrously large assembly, but then you have significantly bigger fish to fry instead of trying to introduce deferred execution on your DI registrations.

Comment: I've heard of people complaining of long start up times due to DI containers, and I was just trying to be mindful of that. But no, right now, there's no observable performance issue. It was less of an attempt to prematurely optimize - I just want to make sure I'm not prematurely pessimizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually registration is one time operation and I think in most cases you should not be conserned that much about one time operations performance. Also based on the [docs](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/E960450C.htm) description the second one should register only types which are assignable both to `Form` and `ExpandableDialog`.

If you are concerned about multiple scans you can use `Where` with predicate:

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assembly)
    .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<ExpandableDialog>() || t.IsAssignableTo<Form>())
    .AsSelf();
```

Comment: I didn't see anything about abstract classes. Is it smart enough to avoid those? I think it would have to be, right? I guess more fundamentally, an abstract class can't be assignable because you can't construct it.

Comment: @void.pointer Would not bet on it (though have not checked). Though even if it does not - it should be easy to fix with `.Where(t => !t.IsAbstract)`.

Comment: @void.pointer actually [it is "smart enough"](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/a5c714b12455319d8f7141a8091274e5bf834a37/src/Autofac/Features/Scanning/OpenGenericScanningRegistrationExtensions.cs#L141)

Comment: Is the `AsSelf()` necessary? I assume that already happens because it's finding concrete types. If I'm wrong, what does the default case do if you do not specify `AsSelf()`?

Comment: @void.pointer [`AsSelf`](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html#specifying-services) is default. I just prefer being explicit.